# When does object go out of scope if no variable is assigned?

Tags: java

When does the object of type list, occupying memory, become eligible for garbage collection, Also where is the variable that holds reference to the list ? In the case of code below, there was no variable assigned to it.

CASE 1:

```
for (Integer i : returnList()) { 
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

In case of a code like:

CASE 2:

```
List list = returnList();
for (Integer i : list) { 
    System.out.println(i);
}
   list = null;
```

We can take control of GC, Is there any ways to take care of that in the first case when no variable was assigned ?

To summarize:

1. What is the mechanism of referrence, without a reference variable to list is case 1?
2. Does list get eligible for GC'd when stack frame is popped ?
3. Any way to speed up the eligibility for GC'ing ?

Comment: Why are you worrying about when the object is eligible for GC? Smells of needless micro-optimization. (I didn't downvote btw)

Comment: And answer for most of your questions are, implementation dependent

Comment: `list` isn't an object. It's a variable. It's *very* important to distinguish between variables and objects. Objects don't have scope, and variables aren't garbage collected...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the mechanism of referrence, without a reference variable to list is case 1?

There is an implicit reference to the list. This can be seen by understanding that enhanced `for` like that is translated into:

```
for(Iterator e = returnList().iterator(); e.hasNext(); ) {
    Integer i = (Integer)e.Next();
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Here, `e` has a reference to an iterator on `returnList`, which *itself* has a reference to `returnList`. Thus, `returnList` is rooted as long as `e` is rooted which is *only* true while control is in the `for` loop. When control leaves the `for` body, `e` is eligible for collection, so `returnList` is eligible for collection.

Of course, all of this is assuming that

1. The owner of `returnList` isn't maintaining a reference to its return value.
2. The same list hasn't been returned to another caller and that *other* caller isn't maintaining a reference to the same list.

> Does list get GC'd when stack frame is popped ?

Not necessarily. It will be eligible for collection when the JVM can determine that the referrent has no rooted references to it. Note that it does not necessarily immediately get collected.

> Any way to speed up GC in case 1.

It can't be collected any sooner than control leaving the `for` loop. It *might* be collected after control leaves the `for` loop. Let the JVM worry about this.

Note that you can *attempt* a manual garbage collection via

```
System.gc();
```

but note that this might exhibit worse behavior because if it triggers a garbage collection, it *might* be a *full* garbage collection. Note that the JVM can [*ignore* this request](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6668279). You might be wasting a lot of CPU cycles here. Note that on a system with infinite memory, the garbage collector *never* needs to run. On such a system, requesting the garbage collector could be a complete waste of CPU cycles if the garbage collector obeys your request.

Let the JVM manage the garbage collections. The algorithms for it are *highly* tuned.

Comment: Amazing answer satisfies all my question verbatim. Thanks,

Comment: System.gc() does not force anything. It's a request to GC and it's often ignored. You cannot in anyway force GC.

Comment: @Xabster: You're correct; thanks for the clarification; I've updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

From **SCJP page 256-257**

> The garbage collector does some magical, unknown operations, and when
>   it discovers an object that can't be reached by any live thread,it
>   will consider that object as eligible for deletion, and it might even
>   delete it at some point. (You guessed it; it also might not ever
>   delete it.) When we talk about reaching an object, we're really
>   talking about having a reachable reference variable that refers to the
>   object in question. If our Java program has a reference variable that
>   refers to an object, and that reference variable is available to a
>   live thread, then that object is considered reachable.

Setting an object to NULL might help to fasten when the GC deletes the object but it might as well not, you don't have control over that. The JVM will run GC when it senses that memory is running low and you can manually ask it to do so but nothing is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the mechanism of reference, without a reference  variable to
>   list is case 1?

see next answer.

> Does list get GC'd when stack frame is popped ?

The list is created on the heap - but if the only reference to it was on the stack it is eligible to be collected by GC. That doesn't mean that it'll happen any time soon though.

> Any way to speed up GC in case 1.

You can't "speed up" GC, even by calling `System.gc();` you're only "suggesting" that the GC can to do its work - again, it won't necessarily happen any time soon.

There's a lot of sense behind it too: say that your program has 2GB of memory to use and is currently using only 2KB - it does not justify GC stopping your program from running and clean the memory only because some objects are eligible for deletion.

Comment: returnList() on each iteration - It get called only once. It does not get called the number of times of list size.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot take control of GC.It is managed by JVM. What you can manage is what objects should be available for garbage collection. Although , you can find out when garbage collector will run using finalize method. It is always called before an object is deleted

```
public class Demo{    

   static  void create()
     {
         Demo o = new Demo();
     }
     public void finalize()
       {
          System.out.println("GC called");
       }

    public static void main (String ...ar)
     {

       for (long  i=1;i<900000;i++)  //Try changing values here
            {
               create();
            }
    }
}
```

Objects created inside the methods are available for GC when method is returned(just like local variables exist for duration of method).However if the method returns an object, it will not be avialble for garbage collection

```
public class Demo{    

   public void getDate()
     {
        Date o = new Date();
        StringBuffer d = new StringBuffer(o.toString());
        System.out.println(d);
        return o;
     }
    public static void main (String ...ar)
     {
            Date x= getDate();
    }
}
```

In the above code, object d is available for GC when the method returns. But object o will not be available for collection